# Detect if values are repeated and apply order criteria using Laravel and collections

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collect

How can I detect if a value is repeated in a collection? And if it repeats, apply a criterion of order for the following value?

I have the following collection where if the "total" value is repeated I have to sort by the value "next" and if the value "next" also repeats, I must sort by the value "subsequent"

[image]

Following the criteria of order, it would be as follows:

[image]

For now in my code I only have a normal collection:

```
$sales = Sale::select('total', 'next', 'subsequent', 'person_id')->with('person')->get();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this (using [Collection::sort()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-sort) which uses `PHP's` [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) under the hood):

```
$sales = 'Get result...';

$sorted = $sales->sort(function ($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a->total, $b->total)
        ?: strcmp($a->next, $b->next)
        ?: strcmp($a->subsequent, $b->subsequent);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, it has been very helpful. Cheerz